# error: 'unordered_set' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, unordered-set

In C++, I am trying to declare an `unordered_set` simply like this:

```
std::unordered_set<int> k;
```

But it is showing this error:

> error: 'unordered_set' is not a member of 'std'

I am using g++ (GCC) 5.3.0 on windows using MinGW. Here are the things that I have already considered:

1. Adding the header file by `#include <unordered_set>`
2. Upgrading MinGW
3. Using the flag `-std=gnu++11`. (This is not generating any executable or error, not sure if it doing anything or not)

How to fix it and compile my code successfully?

Comment: have you included the header `<unordered_set>` ?

Comment: Try `-std=c++11` switch.

Comment: @Tejendra He specifically mentions trying that in the question.

Comment: Yes. I mentioned that too in my question. @Tejendra

Comment: `-std=c++11` and `-std=gnu++11` are different.  What happens when you just try to use `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @AbhipsoGhosh Try pSoLT 's solution

Comment: @AbhipsoGhosh Remember to add '@username' to your comments when answering a question, so that others can know which question you are answering.

Comment: Is your code like this? https://godbolt.org/g/wdARqh  because that works with GCC 5.3.

Comment: In case of `-std=c++11` too, nothing is being generated. No errors, no exe files. @pSoLT

Comment: @AbhipsoGhosh can you pleas post how do you compile the code ?

Comment: I just tried compiling your code. Same problem. So it's probably a compiling issue, not a problem in the code @JhonZwinck

Comment: As I mentioned, I have MinGW installed in windows, and I am compiling using g++ @pSoLT

Comment: @AbhipsoGhosh I mean how do you use g++. Post the command that you use to compile.

Comment: When I use `g++ example.cpp` it shows `error: 'unordered_set' is not a member of 'std` and when I use the flag, i.e `g++ -std=c++11 example.cpp` it does not generate any error or executable. @pSoLT

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `-std=c++11` switch and specify output file.

```
g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program
```